# Upload Image Controller in MVC3 app not working after deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Title kind of says it all. When I am running this in localhost everything works fine, today I deployed to run some testing and BAM! not working. And I for some reason cannot enable the errors to display so I am not sure what is wrong, or really how to even debug this..

Here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DarkRobot.Models;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.IO;

namespace DarkRobot.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Upload/
    private DarkRobotEntities1 db = new DarkRobotEntities1();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string name)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            Image image = new Image();
            image.RelativeLocation = "/Images/" + file.FileName;
            image.Title = name;
            db.Images.Add(image);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    }

    public ActionResult Confirm()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

And here is Index

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="file" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="name" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

If there is anything else you need to try to figure this out, I will gladly update the question. I am fairly new to MVC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same code works in your development, I Strongly believe it is a **permission** issue. Make sure the directory you are trying to upload to, have sufficient permissions to write a file to that.

Comment: Yep. I am an idiot. Called the server dude, he fixed up the permissions, and now we are good to go. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the error, what kind of error your getting. But if it is working in local the only remains on server is the **folder permission**. You should have sufficient permission